# Не сохраняется добавление записи в БД, EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть банальная табличка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создана она как локальная база (.mdf)
Пишу добавление:

```
ProjEntities context = new ProjEntities();
context.Tables.Add(new Table
{
    ProductName = "Book",
    Price = 85
});

context.SaveChanges();
```

Изменения не добавлялись в базу. Хотя, если сразу за сохранением с контекста выбрать записи в список, то добавленная запись есть.

Comment: Подключение не актуально уже. Снова работает. И данные что есть в базе - выбирает. А новые в БД не попадают.

Comment: База локальная, при билде заново копируется из папки проекта в папку bin, затирая сохраненные данные?

Comment: @TheOwl в какой момент данные теряются? После перезапуска приложения?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Под локальной базой обчыно подразумевается подключение к SQL Express / SQL Local DB с указанием `AttachDBFileName = |DataDirectory|\mydatabase.mdf`.

`|DataDirectory|` в случае не-ASP.NET приложения означает "та папка, в которой лежит exe файл". Т.е. это скорее всего не папка проекта, в которой лежат исходники, а папка bin.

Т.е. при указании пути через `|DataDirectory|` программа работает не с mdf-файлом, добавленным в проект, а с его *копией* в bin.

Это не является спецификой EF, то же самое происходит и при ручной работе с SQL через ADO.NET.

Поэтому при таком способе подключения обычно проявляются две связанных проблемы.

- **Проблема 1:** изменения, внесенные программой "не видны" в базе данных.
  **Причина:** программа работает с копией файла в bin, а разработчик проверяет на наличие изменений оригинал в папке проекта.
  **Решение:** исправляется просмотром файла из bin.
- **Проблема 2:** изменения, внесенные программой, теряются при перезапуске программы из студии (по <kbd>F5</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>).
  **Причина:** - mdf файл по умолчанию добавляется проект с Build Action = Content, и настройкой Copy To Output Folder = Always. Это означает, что при перестроении приложения (при повторном его запуске из студии) файл базы из проекта копируется в папку bin, заменяя лежащий там файл, в который были сохранены данные при прошлом запуске.
   **Решение:** исправляется сменой значения `Copy To Output Folder` для mdf-файла в проекте на `If Newer`.