# Не работает добавление в бд

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework

Привет!Сделал добавление в бд но после нажатия на кнопку ничего не происходит(ошибок не появляется,программа не зависает).Закрыв программу и зайдя чтобы проверить добавились ли данные я вижу что все осталось без изменений.Для работы использовал Entity Framework.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class PlusRecepies : Form
    {
        public PlusRecepies()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void PlusToFlp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var label1 = new Label();
            flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(label1);
            label1.Text = ProductPlus.Text;
        }



        private void AddRecepieToDB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Db1Context context = new Db1Context();
            Recipe recipe = new Recipe
            {
                Instructions = RecepiePRText.Text,
                Name = NameRecipe.Text,
                Prop_Time = Convert.ToInt32(PropTime.Text)
            };

            context.Recipe.Add(recipe);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код с выводом

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class PlusRecepies : Form
    {
        public PlusRecepies()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void PlusToFlp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var label1 = new Label();
            flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(label1);
            label1.Text = ProductPlus.Text;
        }



        private void AddRecepieToDB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Db1Context context = new Db1Context();
            Recipe recipe = new Recipe
            {
                Instructions = RecepiePRText.Text,
                Name = NameRecipe.Text,
                Prop_Time = Convert.ToInt32(PropTime.Text)
            };

            foreach (Recipe recipes in context.Recipe)
                textBox1.Text = recipes.Name;

            context.Recipe.Add(recipe);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Db1Context context = new Db1Context();


            foreach (Recipe recipes in context.Recipe)
                textBox1.Text= recipes.Name;
        }


    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Контекст

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class Db1Context : DbContext
    {
        public Db1Context()
            : base("name=Db1Context")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Ingredients> Ingredients { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Recipe> Recipe { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<RecipeIngredient> RecipeIngredient { get; set; }
    }
}
```

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="connstrng" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\user\Desktop\WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;" />
    <add name="WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Settings.Database1ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="Db1Context" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Db1.csdl|res://*/Db1.ssdl|res://*/Db1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: А при клике на кнопку метод вообще запускается?

Comment: Да вызывается,создавал двойным кликом по кнопке.

Comment: А дебагером пробовали пройтись? Возможно в настройках прописана одна база а вы проверяете другую. Можно попробовать из неё что-нибудь вывести.

Comment: Вывод работает,добавил скрин и код.

Comment: Нужен код модели и контекста. Возможно потому что нету ID у модели, пока непонятно.

Comment: Хм...Попробовал нажать второй раз на кнопку и вывело то что я последним добавил.

Comment: После перезапуска программы как будто стираются данные.

Comment: Строку соединения можно глянуть? Есть ощущение, что вы пишете в БД, которая рядом с exe файлом в каталоге bin/debug, а проверяете потом другую БД.

Comment: Добавил контекст,модель не поместилась в 30 000 строк)

Comment: Добавил весь апп конфиг с строкой соеденения

Comment: у вас там аж 3 строки соединения :) используется, скорее всего строка - Db1Context - и значит вы просто не в той базе проверяете наличие изменений. Посмотрите вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/426203/ - судя по всему, вы именно на эти грабли наступили

Comment: Я сменил настройки бд как написано в ответе который вы скинули но все также не работает,данные не сохраняются.

Comment: Так вы же написали что выводит то что добавили. Значит всё сохраняется а потом скидывается...

Comment: Ну а мне нужно чтобы не скидывалось :)

Comment: @OleksandrTatarinov попробуйте запустить вашу программу напрямую из папки bin, а не из visual studio. У вас данные скорее всего не сохраняются потому, что вы подключились к вашей оригинальной (пустой) базе из студии (или из приложения по connection string "connstrng"). Это меняет дату у файла и делает его "более новым". Отключайтесь и проверяйте что дата у файла, который лежит в папке проекта (bin) не меняется сама по себе.

Comment: @OleksandrTatarinov ну и просто в логи билда (Output) посмотрите при запуске - там же явно пишет, скопировало файл или нет

Comment: Спасибо все заработало и я все понял)))

Comment: Только ответом нечего отметить))