# запись не добавляется в бд

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь добавить новые данные в бд, но вставка не осуществляется и ошибки не выводятся. Может кто подскажет где ошибка

```
print.Click += (s, el) => {
            //MessageBox.Show("dasdasd");
            for (int j = 0; j < COR; j++)
            {

                DB = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|IskoGlass.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
                 DB.Open();
                 SqlCommand cmdpast = DB.CreateCommand();
                 cmdpast.CommandText = "INSERT INTO orders (Name, LastName, IdNum, ThelNum, Adress, orderGroup, GlassId, GlassName, GlassWidth, GlassHeight, GlassCount, GlassArea, GlassTotalArea, GlassPrice, GlassTotalPrice) VALUES (@Name, @LastName, @IdNum, @ThelNum, @Adress, @orderGroup, @GlassId, @GlassName, @GlassWidth, @GlassHeight, @GlassCount, @GlassArea, @GlassTotalArea, @GlassPrice, @GlassTotalPrice)";
                 cmdpast.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

                 cmdpast.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", Convert.ToString(txtName.Text)));
                 cmdpast.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LastName", Convert.ToString(txtLastName.Text)));
                 cmdpast.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IdNum", Convert.ToString(txtIdNum.Text)));
                 cmdpast.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ThelNum", Convert.ToString(txtTelNum.Text)));
                 cmdpast.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Adress", Convert.ToString(txtAdress.Text)));

                 cmdpast.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@orderGroup", Convert.ToInt32(labelOrderNUm.Text)));
                 cmdpast.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@GlassId", Convert.ToInt32(cbGlassId[j].Text)));
                 cmdpast.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@GlassName", Convert.ToString(txtGlassName[j].Text)));
                 cmdpast.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@GlassWidth", Convert.ToDouble(txtGlassWidth[j].Text.Replace('.', ','))));
                 cmdpast.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@GlassHeight", Convert.ToDouble(txtGlassHeight[j].Text.Replace('.', ','))));
                 cmdpast.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@GlassCount", Convert.ToInt32(txtGlassCount[j].Text)));
                 cmdpast.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@GlassArea", Convert.ToDouble(txtGlassArea[j].Text.Replace('.', ','))));
                 cmdpast.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@GlassTotalArea", Convert.ToDouble(txtGlassTotalArea[j].Text.Replace('.', ','))));
                 cmdpast.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@GlassPrice", Convert.ToDouble(txtGlassPrice[j].Text.Replace('.', ','))));
                 cmdpast.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@GlassTotalPrice", Convert.ToDouble(txtGlassTotalPrice[j].Text.Replace('.', ','))));

                 cmdpast.ExecuteNonQuery();


            }
            /*PrintForm pf = new PrintForm(Convert.ToInt32(labelOrderNUm.Text));
            pf.Show();*/
        };
```

Comment: Скорее всего вы не в той базе наличие записи проверяете: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/426203/. |DataDirectory| - это файлы базы в папке bin.

Comment: Спасибо. Только начинаю изучать. Странно что сам не догадался.

Comment: Соединение с СУБД надо вынести за пределы цикла, а также не забывайте закрывать соединение после выхода из цикла.